# DataFrame transpose from List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As most pandas problems, I am guessing the problem has been dealt with before, but I can't find a direct answer and I'm also worried about performance. My dataset is large, so I'm hoping to find the *most efficient* way of doing this.

**The Problem**
I have 2 dataframes - dfA contains a list of id's from dfB. I'd like to

1. transpose those IDs as columns
2. replace the IDs with a value looked up from dfB
3. collapse repeated columns and aggregate with sum

Here's an illustration:

**dfA**

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'a_id':['0000001','0000002','0000003','0000004'],
                    'list_of_b_id':[['2','3','7'],[],['1','2','3','4'],['6','7']]
                   })

+------+--------------+
| a_id | list_of_b_id |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | [2, 3, 7]    |
+------+--------------+
| 2    | []           |
+------+--------------+
| 3    | [1, 2, 3, 4] |
+------+--------------+
| 4    | [6, 7]       |
+------+--------------+
```

**dfB**

```
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'b_id':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
                   'replacement': ['Red','Red','Blue','Red','Green','Blue','Red']
                  })

+------+-------------+
| b_id | replacement |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | Red         |
+------+-------------+
| 2    | Red         |
+------+-------------+
| 3    | Blue        |
+------+-------------+
| 4    | Red         |
+------+-------------+
| 5    | Orange      |
+------+-------------+
| 6    | Blue        |
+------+-------------+
| 7    | Red         |
+------+-------------+
```

**Goal (Final Result)**
Here is what I'm hoping to eventually get to, in the most efficient way possible.

In reality, I may have over 5M obs in both dfA and dfB, and ~50 unique values for replacement in dfB, which explains why I need to do this in dynamic fashion and not just hard-code it.

```
+------+-----+------+
| a_id | Red | Blue |
+------+-----+------+
| 1    | 2   | 1    |
+------+-----+------+
| 2    | 0   | 0    |
+------+-----+------+
| 3    | 3   | 1    |
+------+-----+------+
| 4    | 1   | 1    |
+------+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all lists are flattening by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'id':np.repeat(dfA['a_id'], dfA['list_of_b_id'].str.len()),
                    'b': np.concatenate(dfA['list_of_b_id'])})

print (df)  
   b       id
0  2  0000001
0  3  0000001
0  7  0000001
2  1  0000003
2  2  0000003
2  3  0000003
2  4  0000003
3  6  0000004
3  7  0000004
```

Then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created from `dfB`, which is used for 
[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for counts, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and add missing values by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['id',df['b'].map(dfB.set_index('b_id')['replacement'])])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(dfA['a_id'].unique(), fill_value=0))
print (df)
b        Blue  Red
id                
0000001     1    2
0000002     0    0
0000003     1    3
0000004     1    1
```

---

```
print (df['b'].map(dfB.set_index('b_id')['replacement']))
0     Red
0    Blue
0     Red
2     Red
2     Red
2    Blue
2     Red
3    Blue
3     Red
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: On a sample of 50K records in dfA and 5M records in dfB, this took 0.67 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

```
  a = [['2','3','7'],[],['1','2','3','4'],['6','7']]
  b =['Red','Red','Blue','Red','Green','Blue','Red']
  res = []
  for line in a:
    tmp = {}
    for ele in line:
      tmp[b[int(ele)-1]] = tmp.get(b[int(ele)-1], 0) +1
    res.append(tmp)

  print pd.DataFrame(res).fillna(0)

   Blue  Red
0   1.0  2.0
1   0.0  0.0
2   1.0  3.0
3   1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
In [5611]: dft = (dfA.set_index('a_id')['list_of_b_id']
                     .apply(pd.Series)
                     .stack()
                     .replace(dfB.set_index('b_id')['replacement'])
                     .reset_index())

In [5612]: (dft.groupby(['a_id', 0]).size().unstack()
               .reindex(dfA['a_id'].unique(), fill_value=0))
Out[5612]:
0        Blue  Red
a_id
0000001     1    2
0000002     0    0
0000003     1    3
0000004     1    1
```

---

Details

```
In [5613]: dft
Out[5613]:
      a_id  level_1     0
0  0000001        0   Red
1  0000001        1  Blue
2  0000001        2   Red
3  0000003        0   Red
4  0000003        1   Red
5  0000003        2  Blue
6  0000003        3   Red
7  0000004        0  Blue
8  0000004        1   Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
pd.concat([dfA, dfA.list_of_b_id.apply(lambda x: dfB[dfB.b_id.isin(x)].replacement.value_counts())], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d=dfB.set_index('b_id').T.to_dict('r')[0]

dfA['list_of_b_id']=dfA['list_of_b_id'].apply(lambda x : [d.get(k,k) for k in x])
pd.concat([dfA,pd.get_dummies(dfA['list_of_b_id'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)],axis=1)


Out[66]: 
      a_id           list_of_b_id  Blue  Red
0  0000001       [Red, Blue, Red]   1.0  2.0
1  0000002                     []   NaN  NaN
2  0000003  [Red, Red, Blue, Red]   1.0  3.0
3  0000004            [Blue, Red]   1.0  1.0
```